# MySQL query in R to compare with certain value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, r

```
 args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
 id = as.character(args)
 mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'manu',host = 'localhost') 

 sql<-sprintf("select * from net where ips1=%s;",id) 
 up = dbGetQuery(mysqlconnection, sql)
```

I am trying to retrieve records from the table net using R.
I want to retrieve the records with a specific id which is being passed as a command line argument.However i am getting an error near  " ips1=%s ",saying that the SQL syntax which i used is incorrect. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to enclose the string value to compare in single quotes `'`:

```
sql <- sprintf("select * from net where ips1='%s';",id)
```